# How to update Managed Metadata (Taxonomy) in different language?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a working  multilingual (variations) SP2010 website with 2 extra language packs installed: Dutch and French.

I programmatically imported the taxonomy data into my SharePoint 2010 Managed Metadata Service.

Now, I want to change name of the French/Dutch term and add labels (synonyms) but I can't figure out how it's done.

So my question :
*How can I programmatically update the Dutch/French equivalent of a certain Term in my Managed Term Store?*

Any ideas? Thanks.
W

edit: clarified that my site is already multilingual with language packs installed.

```
TaxonomySession taxonomySession = new TaxonomySession(site);
TermStore termStore = taxonomySession.TermStores["MyTermStore"];
Group group = termStore.Groups["MyGroup"];
TermSet englishTermSet = group.TermSets["myTermSets"];

termEnglish= englishTermSet.CreateTerm("Services", 1033);
```

// TODO: update the Dutch and French versions.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that you first need to install the SharePoint Foundation Language Pack, and after that the SharePoint Server Language Pack.

Go to Term Store Management Tool in Central Admin
In Managed Metadata Service Properties screen, enable the new language by adding it as a Working Language.

Set the language while Creating Term using `WorkingLanguage` [property](http://207.46.16.248/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.termstore.workinglanguage.aspx)

Comment: My language packs are installed. I have to full functionality available. Everything works as expected (including multilingual site, (variations)). I just can't figure out how to adjust a term in French or Dutch